# RecyclerView field to search

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm creating an app todolist in Kotlin. I add a field (editText) to searching through tasks, but sometimes when I type something in editText field, app crash with this error

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.todo_app, PID: 10500
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionTaskViewHolder{ae4ea30 position=2 id=-1, oldPos=0, pLpos:0 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{5e2e21c VFED..... ......I. 0,0-1080,1273 #7f090175 app:id/rv}, adapter:com.example.todo_app.VIew.TaskAdapter@aecd885, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager@c3a81, context:com.example.todo_app.VIew.MainActivity@3475126
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:6590)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6796)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6757)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6753)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2362)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1662)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1622)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:687)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:4591)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4346)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4919)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
2023-10-11 18:20:24.466 10500-10500 AndroidRuntime          com.example.todo_app                 E      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Main Activity

```
    package com.example.todo_app.VIew

    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.text.Editable
    import android.text.TextWatcher
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    import com.example.todo_app.Model.Task
    import com.example.todo_app.ViewModel.TaskViewModel
    import com.example.todo_app.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
    import java.util.logging.Handler

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        private val mainVM = TaskViewModel()
        private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
        private var taskList = mutableListOf<Task>()
        private lateinit var adapter: TaskAdapter
        private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView


        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)

            //Read list
            taskList = mainVM.readListFromFile(this, "daneListy").sortedWith(compareByDescending {!it.status }).toMutableList()

            //Search
            binding.etSearch.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                    // przed zmianą tekstu
                }

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                    // podczas zmiany tekstu
                    filterTasks(s.toString())
                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                    // po zmianie tekste
                }
            })

            //RecyclerView setup
            recyclerView = binding.rv
            adapter = TaskAdapter(taskList)
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

            binding.btnAdd.setOnClickListener{
                //Validation
                if (binding.etAdd.text.isEmpty()) {
                    binding.etAdd.hint = "To pole nie może być puste"
                } else {
                    // Add task
                    val textToAdd = binding.etAdd.text.toString()
                    taskList.add(Task(textToAdd, "opis", false))
                    adapter.notifyItemInserted(taskList.size - 1)
                    binding.etAdd.setText("")
                }
            }
        }
        private fun filterTasks(query: String) {
            val filteredTasks = taskList.filter { it.title.contains(query, ignoreCase = true) }
            adapter.updateTaskList(filteredTasks)
        }
        override fun onPause() {
            super.onPause()
            //Save list
            mainVM.saveListToFile(this, taskList, "daneListy")
        }
    }
```

TaskAdapter

```
package com.example.todo_app.VIew

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.todo_app.databinding.ListItemBinding
import com.example.todo_app.Model.Task
import java.util.logging.Handler


class TaskAdapter(private var tasks: List<Task>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.TaskViewHolder>() {
    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun updateTaskList(newTaskList: List<Task>) {
        tasks = newTaskList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    class TaskViewHolder(private val binding: ListItemBinding, private val adapter: TaskAdapter) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(task: Task, tasksList: List<Task>) {
            binding.cbTask.text = task.title
            binding.cbTask.isChecked = task.status

            //Checkbox strike through line
            binding.cbTask.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->

                task.status = isChecked
                // write here your code for example ...
                if (isChecked) {
                    binding.cbTask.paintFlags = binding.cbTask.paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
                    adapter.notifyItemMoved(bindingAdapterPosition, tasksList.size - 1)
                } else {
                    binding.cbTask.paintFlags = binding.cbTask.paintFlags and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
                    adapter.notifyItemMoved(bindingAdapterPosition, 0)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TaskViewHolder {
        val binding = ListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return TaskViewHolder(binding, this)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TaskViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentTask = tasks[position]
        holder.bind(currentTask, tasks)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = tasks.size
}
```

TaskViewModel

```
package com.example.todo_app.ViewModel

import android.content.Context
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.example.todo_app.Model.Task
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException

class TaskViewModel: ViewModel() {
    fun saveListToFile(context: Context, list: List<Task>, fileName: String) {
        val FILE_EXTENSION = ".json"
        try {
            val file = File(context.filesDir, fileName + FILE_EXTENSION)
            val gson = Gson()
            val jsonString = gson.toJson(list)
            file.writeText(jsonString)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    fun readListFromFile(context: Context, fileName: String): List<Task> {
        val FILE_EXTENSION = ".json"
        try {
            val file = File(context.filesDir, fileName + FILE_EXTENSION)
            if (!file.exists()) {
                return emptyList()
            }
            val gson = Gson()
            val jsonString = file.readText()
            val listType = object : TypeToken<List<Task>>() {}.type
            return gson.fromJson(jsonString, listType)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return emptyList()
    }
}
```

Task

```
    package com.example.todo_app.Model

    data class Task(
        var title: String,
        val description: String,
        var status: Boolean)
```

I want an app where user type something in search field and the app shows tasks that contains phrase user search.

Comment: give more detail about error...

Answer (score 0):

Two recommendations:

- Use `tasks[holder.absoluteAdapterPosition]` instead of `tasks[position]`
- Don't pass the Adapter to ViewHolder. Declare your ViewHolder as `inner class ...` to access Adapter fields.

I think the problem is you use `bindingAdapterPosition` inside your ViewHolder. That is meant to be used when we merge multiple adapters, So don't.
Use `absoluteAdapterPosition` of the ViewHolder itself.